# Perfect match of record from a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a following data in a table tableA.

```
user_id subject
1        English
1        Science
1        Maths
2        English
2        Maths
```

I need to fetch all users who are having subject English and Maths only.

I tried the query like `SELECT user_id from tableA where subject = 'English' OR subject = 'Match'`.

How to get all `user_id` which perfectly matches in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You mean `OR subject = 'Maths'`, no?

Answer (score 0):

A single record can not have both subjects at the same time. So you need to build a group for every user

```
SELECT user_id 
from tableA 
where subject in ('English', 'Match')
group by user_id
having count(distinct subject) = 2
```

Group by the user and then you can select only those having both subjects

Comment: Thanks juergen, Subjects in where clause may also increase to 3 subjects. There will be n number of userids and their subjects may also vary

Comment: The number in `having count(distinct subject) = 2` must be the number of subjects you are looking for. If you want to check for 3 subjects then use `having count(distinct subject) = 3`. The number of users does not matter